# appscript on OSX 10.6.3 / Python 2.6.1

Tags: python, macos, setuptools, sourceforge-appscript

I am having some trouble getting `appscript` installed on OS/X 10.6.3 / Python 2.6.1. When I issue

`sudo easy_install appscript`

I get "unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory".  Even when I do `export CC=/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` (a valid gcc-4.2 executable), `easy_install` barks.

What could be the issue?

*Disclaimer:* OS/X newbie at the helm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rerun the Xcode installer and check "UNIX Development" - it will put compilers in /usr/bin in addition to /Developer.

Comment: yep, that took care of the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the solution proposed is sufficient in many cases, as (for example) I already have the tools in /usr/bin and get the same error.

The problem is that gcc is being invoked with an -arch ppc flag, which generally is not supported any longer.

You need to (a)
  set ARCHFLAGS in the shell environment so that is it 
  something like '-arch i386 -arch x86_64'
or for (b) for a permanent fix:

edit 
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python*/distutils/sysconfig.py

to change 
   archflags = '-arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64'
or be 
   archflags = '-arch i386 -arch x86_64'