# python easy_install fails with "assembler for architecture ppc not installed" on Mac OS X

Tags: python, xcode, macos, installation, powerpc

```
bash-3.2$ sudo easy_install appscript  
Password:  
Searching for appscript  
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/appscript/  
Reading http://appscript.sourceforge.net  
Best match: appscript 1.0.0  
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/appscript/appscript-1.0.0.tar.gz#md5=6619b637037ea0f391f45870c13ae38a  
Processing appscript-1.0.0.tar.gz  
Running appscript-1.0.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-C4d1az/appscript-1.0.0/egg-dist-tmp-yVTHww  
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed  
Installed assemblers are:  
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64  
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
```

I'm a pretty big noob at this stuff (I've learned to use python and unix a bit, but I've never had to deal with installation.)  Earlier I was getting an error related to gcc-4.2 not being found, and I found some posts that recommended reinstalling XCode.  I went with 4.0 (bad choice?) and now I get this.  I've got no idea what to do at this point.

Comment: it appears you're running on a PPC Mac and you don't have the GNU assembler for it. unfortunately, I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: If it's 10.6.6, it's not PPC.

Comment: Did you try [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769910/appscript-on-osx-10-6-3-python-2-6-1)? I use Appscript successfully under Macports, if that is an option for you.

Comment: I did, which is what prompted me to update XCode.  I definitely checked off the UNIX Development option.

Answer (score 77):

This happened for me after having upgraded to XCode 4; I haven't had time to figure out what went wrong during the upgrade (or whether this is the intended behaviour), but the following workaround works for me:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" easy_install whatever
```

The `ARCHFLAGS` trick works with `setup.py` as well:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" python setup.py install
```

Comment: This got me pointed in the right direction for a different library that was having the same issue. Apparently XCode 4 no longer supports ppc which these extensions are trying to build for. Not entirely sure if the proper fix is in Python or easy_install though. This link verifies lack of ppc support: http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Mar/msg00215.html

Comment: damn, what the hell!  this took me so long to figure out, thanks for posting this.

Comment: This was ridiculously helpful installing matplotlib with the Apple-supplied Python and Xcode 4. I swapped out `x86_64` for `i386` in the `easy_install` command for a 64-bit Python and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me, when I was trying to install urwid. Many thanks!

Comment: Works for me too!  I did this: export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" ;  pip install lxml

Comment: For some reason, this works perfectly when setting the ARCHFLAGS on the *same line* as calling `pip` or `easy_install`, but setting the ARCHFLAGS on a separate terminal command or in my profile is ineffective.

Comment: @CodyHess: have you tried exporting ARCHFLAGS from your profile? (I.e., ``export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"``?)

Answer (score 15):

I found another solution [here](http://martinkou.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-solve-assembler-for-architecture.html) which solves the problem once and for all.  It turns out XCode4 still has the ppc assembler.  You just need a symlink to it in the right place:

```
$ sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc /Developer/usr/libexec/gcc/darwin
$ sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc /usr/libexec/gcc/darwin
```

Fixed the problem for me with XCode4 installed on Snow Leopard.

**EDIT**: I tried other solutions, which worked in some cases, but invariably encountered a package that hardcoded the PPC requirement somewhere.  Providing the PPC assembler got rid of all these problems once and for all.

Comment: Yay, this is great, thanks. However, note that this probably works only for those who have the iOS SDK installed. (Cannot check it, I do have the iOS SDK and it works for me, but I guess that there is no iPhoneOS.platform folder in the default XCode 4 distribution).

Answer (score 1):

For me, the key was the ppc assembler, not the ARCHFLAGS stuff. But, the suggestion above didn't work; I didn't have the files in those locations. But with some tinkering and poking around, I found that I did have the ppc assember at `/usr/bin/as`. I first tried `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/as /usr/libexec/as/ppc/as`, but that failed (something about could not fork process...??). So I ended up just doing `sudo cp /usr/bin/as /usr/libexec/as/ppc/as`, and that worked (I think I had to do some `sudo mkdir`s along that path, as well).

Answer (score 0):

Using the system Pythons on Mac OS X 10.6, you'll need to have the gcc-4.2 from the Apple Xcode Developer Tools installed to build extension modules, like with Appscript.  Other products may need the Xcode gcc-4.0 so you should install them both.  They co-exist just fine.

Comment: Where can one get a hold of gcc-4.0? I keep running into problems as I'm trying to install various modules for Python 2.7 under OS X 10.6. Continuous complaints about the lack of gcc-4.0.

Comment: gcc-4.0 is included with the default Xcode 3.x Developer Tools for OS X 10.6 (but may not be included with the new optional Xcode 4).  I believe 3.2.6 is the most recent. From the Xcode 3.x installer, you may also need to select the "Mac OS X 10.4 SDK" subpackage which is not selected by default.