# Error compiling Cython on Mac 10.6

Tags: xcode, cython, kinect, osx-snow-leopard

Trying to install Cython so I can use openKinect Python wrapper.

I downloaded Xcode from the appstore (no install options. lame).

Im getting the following compile errors when trying to install

I also tried easy_install and that failed as well.

Error Code below

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/Cython/Plex
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -    
Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe - 
I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c  
./Cython/Plex/Scanners.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-  
2.6/./Cython/Plex/Scanners.o
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler  
(/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as)  
for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
./Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:6694: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
```

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with XCode (which is why this isn't an answer), but the problem looks to be that you're trying to create a universal binary, while you probably want to restrict yourself to x86. If there's an option for that, I would use it.

Comment: There were no mention of options in the documentation, would the option be passed as part of settings.py or 'python settings.py install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before your command (but after any `sudo`) put

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
```

(When installing, you may want to omit the arch you don't have)

I do not have a Mac, I'm just putting through advice from [python easy_install fails with "assembler for architecture ppc not installed" on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256397/python-easy-install-fails-with-assembler-for-architecture-ppc-not-installed-on)

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Now If only I could figure out the other dependencies for this python wrapper...

Comment: I wish i could give you more points for how helpful this answer was. Especially given how much more time i would have spent had you not given it...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (with Cython installation and other modules).
Using krzysz00's advice, here are the exact steps (Mac OS X 10.6.8) :

```
$ uname -a
Darwin machine_name 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386            
$ cd Cython-0.14.1
$ sudo su - 
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
# python ./setup.py install
# exit
$
$ which cython
/usr/local/bin/cython
```